# Pocket API: how to modify data using callAPIMethod?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, pocket

I would like to edit the data saved at Pocket using [Pocket API](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/modify) with [iOS SDK](https://github.com/Pocket/Pocket-ObjC-SDK). 
However, although the preparation method is tried, no response and error also come on the contrary.

As a premise

1. URLs can be added using other API (saveURL).
2. Permissions of the registered application are 'Add' and 'Modify'.

Is there any advice? Thanks.

```
NSError* error;
NSArray *actions = @[@{ @"action": @"delete", @"item_id": @"456853615" }];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: actions
                                                   options: kNilOptions
                                                     error: &error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

// On ios simulator access_token is saved in NSUserDefaults, but on device in keychain.
// see https://github.com/Pocket/Pocket-ObjC-SDK/blob/master/SDK/PocketAPI.m#L718
NSString *accessToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"PocketAPI.token"];    
NSDictionary* argumentDictionary = @{@"consumer_key": @"<MY_CONSUMER_KEY>",
                                     @"access_token": accessToken,
                                          @"actions": jsonString};


[[PocketAPI sharedAPI] callAPIMethod: @"v3/send"
                      withHTTPMethod: PocketAPIHTTPMethodPOST
                           arguments: argumentDictionary
                             handler: ^(PocketAPI *api, NSString *apiMethod, NSDictionary *response, NSError *error){
                                 NSLog(@"response %@", [response description]); // response (null)
                                 NSLog(@"error %@", [error localizedDescription]); // response (null)
                             }];
```

Answer (score 2):

Drop the the API version, consumer_key & access_token. These are appended by the SDK.

```
NSError* error;
NSArray *actions = @[@{ @"action": @"delete", @"item_id": @"456853615" }];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: actions
                                               options: kNilOptions
                                                 error: &error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary* argumentDictionary = @{@"actions":jsonString};

[[PocketAPI sharedAPI] callAPIMethod:@"send"
                  withHTTPMethod:PocketAPIHTTPMethodPOST
                       arguments:argumentDictionary
                         handler:^(PocketAPI *api, NSString *apiMethod, NSDictionary *response, NSError *error){
                             NSLog(@"response %@", [response description]);
                             NSLog(@"error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                         }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use the NSDictionary to argumentDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *argumentDictionary = @{@"actions" : @[@{@"action" : @"delete",
                                                    @"item_id" : @"456853615"}]};

[[PocketAPI sharedAPI] callAPIMethod:@"send"
                      withHTTPMethod:PocketAPIHTTPMethodPOST
                           arguments:argumentDictionary
                             handler:^(PocketAPI *api, NSString *apiMethod, NSDictionary *response, NSError *error){
                                 NSLog(@"response %@", [response description]);
                                 NSLog(@"error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                             }];
```